# C++ operator overloading and associated namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, clang, argument-dependent-lookup

The following simplified example compiles in `gcc` and `Visual Studio`, but fails in `clang` !?

```
namespace N
{
    struct A {};

    template <typename T>
    double operator+ (T a, double d) {return d;}

    template <typename T>
    double operator+ (double d, T a) {return d;}
}

void test()
{
    N::A a;
    double x;

    double y = a + x;
    double z = x + a;
}
```

As I see it, the templated `operator+` in namespace `N` should be found by ADL.

Why does `clang` disagree ? Is it a bug in `clang` or in the other compilers ?

Here is the compilation error from clang 3.5.1 (tested on coliru), I don't understand what is the problem here...

```
10 : error: overloaded 'operator+' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type
double operator+ (double d, T a) {return d;}
^
18 : note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'N::operator+' requested here
double y = a + x;
^

7 : error: overloaded 'operator+' must have at least one parameter of class or enumeration type
double operator+ (T a, double d) {return d;}
^
19 : note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'N::operator+' requested here
double z = x + a;
^

2 errors generated.
Compilation failed
```

The example is simplified from real life code, of course. The intention is that any class defined inside namespace N has an overloaded operator+ with a double.

Comment: From that error, it looks like it is being found by ADL. Not sure what it's complaining about though

Comment: Note that your test program has undefined behaviour, since `x` is not initialized.

Comment: @KerrekSB You *are* reproducing because you're using gcc while can compile this. [Clang cannot](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd4cfc7eb1cc02d7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by two different CWG issues: [CWG issue 2052](http://wg21.link/cwg2052) and [CWG issue 1391](http://wg21.link/cwg1391).

First, CWG 1391. On encountering `x + a`, the usual name lookup finds, among other overloads,

```
template <typename T> double operator+ (T, double);
```

Template argument deduction is performed by match `T` to the type of the lhs of `+`, which is `double`, so this deduces `T` to be `double`. The second parameter's type contains no template parameter, so is not considered under current rules. To be sure, `N::A` can't be converted to a `double`, so the resulting specialization is not viable, but the current rules say that template argument deduction doesn't care about this; that will be handled in overload resolution.

The proposed resolution to CWG 1391, among other things, adds a new paragraph to the standard:

> If deduction succeeds for all parameters that contain
>   template-parameters that participate in template argument deduction,
>   and all template arguments are explicitly specified, deduced, or
>   obtained from default template arguments, remaining parameters are
>   then compared with the corresponding arguments. For each remaining
>   parameter `P` with a type that was non-dependent before substitution of
>   any explicitly-specified template arguments, if the corresponding
>   argument A cannot be implicitly converted to `P`, deduction fails.
>   [*Note*: Parameters with dependent types in which no template-parameters
>   participate in template argument deduction, and parameters that became
>   non-dependent due to substitution of explicitly-specified template
>   arguments, will be checked during overload resolution. —*end note*]

In other words, if an argument (`a` in our case) corresponding to a non-dependent parameter (`double`) cannot be converted to the parameter's type, deduction would simply fail. So in our case, post-CWG1391 template argument deduction will fail for this overload, and everything would be well.

Clang implements the current rules, however, so deduction succeeds with `T = double`, substitution occurs, and we encounter CWG 2052. Quoting the writeup from Richard Smith (a Clang dev):

> In an example like
>
> ```
>   struct A { operator int(); };
>   template<typename T> T operator<<(T, int);
>   void f(A a) { 1 << a; }
> ```
>
> Template argument deduction succeeds for the operator template,
>   producing the signature `operator<<(int,int)`. The resulting
>   declaration is synthesized and added to the overload set, per 14.8.3
>   [temp.over] paragraph 1. However, this violates the requirement of
>   13.5 [over.oper] paragraph 6,
>
> > An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or
> >     be a non-member function that has at least one parameter whose type is
> >     a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
> >     enumeration.
>
> This is not a SFINAE context, so the program is ill-formed, rather
>   than selecting the built-in operator.

In this case, there's no conversion, so the deduced `operator+(double, double)` is actually not viable, but non-viable candidates are not eliminated until you have built the candidate set, and here building the candidate set is causing a hard error.

The proposed resolution to CWG 2052 will make this case SFINAE instead - also making the original code work. The problem is - Clang is implementing the current version of the standard here, too.

Comment: Why would `operator+(double, double)` be deduced at all in the OP's situation?

Comment: @KerrekSB Given `template <typename T> double operator+ (T, double); double x; N::A a;` and `x + a`, `T` is deduced from the lhs, i.e., `double`. Of course there's no conversion from `N::A` to `double` for the rhs, but template argument deduction doesn't care; that's left for overload resolution.

Comment: Interesting hole in the standard. Thanks for the explanation. I guess clang was right, and GCC/VC will be right.

Comment: @T.C.: Oh, of course -- I was thinking of the other function. Yes, makes sense. This should have been a SFINAE context but isn't. I imagine the CWG issue will be a DR against 11 -- nobody will want this kind of behaviour to depend on the language version.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. According to this answer, I only have two alternatives: a) provide an overloaded operator for each class in namespace N, or b) use CRTP in all classes in namespace N and then define the operators in terms of the common base class. Am I right?

Comment: @dats No, the `enable_if` in the other answer is fine. It causes a deduction failure when `T` is deduced as `double`, so the substitution (to form the ill-formed `operator+(double, double)`) doesn't take place.

Answer (score 3):

It might be complaining because `T` *might* not be a class in that definition. And you are not allowed to redefine the standard `operator+` for arithmetic types IIRC. In your example, there's nothing restricting `T` to be `N::A` for instance.

Adding `typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>{} || std::is_enum<T>{}>` seems to fix it. Visual Studio and GCC might be a bit more lax/lazy about this restriction.

```
namespace N
{
    struct A {};

    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>{} || std::is_enum<T>{}>>
    double operator+ (T a, double d) {return d;}

    template <typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_class<T>{} || std::is_enum<T>{}>>
    double operator+ (double d, T a) {return d;}
}

 void test()
 {
    N::A a;
    double x;

    double y = a + x;
    double z = x + a;
 }
```

Comment: I don't think that problem should be a concern until instantiation. For example, if you [remove one of the overloads](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a361da7a886c1a26) clang won't complain.

Comment: @0x499602D2 True. Something odd is happening here. If you leave in the other addition, http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3dd251ee27581b3, you still get that error popping up.

Comment: The error messages (both the original, and the coliru ones), indicate that it is instantiating the functions with `T = double` in those instances where it fails to compile. `in instantiation of function template specialization 'N::operator+<double>' requested here`

Comment: Yes, I think clang is inadvertantly instantiating the candidates while performing overload resolution.

Comment: According to the answer by T.C I don't think enable_if will solve the problem in clang.

Comment: @dats It definitely fixes the problem. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f82b2eeed3600729